# How to make an entry with dynamic drop down list?

Tags: forms, ee3

I'm a newbie to EE & purchased EE 3.0.4!

The scenario is questions have to be grouped into categories:

In the cpanel,

1. A category has to be chosen from drop down of categories of questions and a question & answer has to be entered as an entry

In front end

1. A category has to be chosen then a question has to be selected in the chosen category and answer for the question will be shown.

I learnt about [relations](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/fieldtypes/relationships.html) and [forms](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/channel/channel_form/) but if i choose a field as relation then i see the variable is printed as it is like {variable_name} but not its value. Creating forms is apparently only for interacting with end user.

Please help me in understanding how to create this in EE way. Can i create category, question and answer tables by myself and write quires with php-mysqli?

**Edit:** Category of questions means set of or group of questions, Its not used to indicated reserved keyword in EE

**Solution**

the [pizza store example](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/fieldtypes/relationships.html#id27) was explained well. I was trying to create stores &  create pizzas under it. where as from example i learned that pizzas has to be created first and then assign them under stores

Comment: So are you using categories or relationship field in control panel? Your description is not completely clear on this

Comment: @YuriSalimovskiy using relationship is throwing variable as it is to front end but not its value. When i say category its not reserved word of EE, i mean category of questions for set of/ group of questions

Comment: How do you plan to show the answers? AJAX? One question and answer per page? A page for all question of a category? One menu of categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Relationship field (i.e. relating question/answer entry to "category" entry), then you need to output the variables like this: `{relationship_field:title}`

[See the docs for more examples](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/fieldtypes/relationships.html#usage-single-related-entries).